What is "overshadowing" or "superposing a signal"?
The term "overshadow" is used heavily in this paper https://rahbari.csec.rit.edu/papers/globecom2022_Dongre_Implicit.pdf
I'm confused as to what it means to "overshadow" a signal. It defines it as superposing a signal on another signal, but I'm not sure what "superposing a signal" is.

Did you link the correct paper? The term "overshadow" doesn't show up in there at all

The term "overshadow" may not be explicitly mentioned in the paper, but the concept is central to the described attacks. The paper discusses a type of attack where an attacker injects a signal (or message) that is superimposed on the legitimate signal. This process, known as overshadowing, involves the attacker sending a crafted signal at the same time as the legitimate one. The attacker's signal is designed to overpower or overshadow the legitimate signal, causing the receiving device to accept the malicious message instead. This can trick the device into thinking the attacker's message is legitimate, leading to potential disruptions or malicious actions.
This figure illustrates how the legitimate message 2 is overridden by the attacker's signal:

